# What's the difference between glob's directory/ and directory/* and directory/** and directory/**/*?

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm using gulp building my development workflow. Gulp and its plugins use glob heavily.

I'm confused about the differences between the followings:

```
directory/ 
directory/* 
directory/** 
directory/**/*
```

I'm not able to make gulp do the things I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt has a pretty good explanation of how globs work http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

```
* matches any number of characters, but not /
** matches any number of characters, including /, as long as it's the only thing
   in a path part. So a/**/b will match a/x/y/b, but a/**b will not.

directory/ = this isn't a glob and would evaluate as expected.
directory/* = will match anything in the directory, but not sub-directories.
directory/** = will match anything in the directory and all subdirectories.
directory/**/* = will match anything in the directory and all subdirectories. 
                 (good for adding a prefix like an extension to the end)
```

Comment: So there's no difference between directory/** and directory/**/* . But I'm still a little confused by directory/* and directory/**. When I use del, the npm module, to clean files. directory/* will delete all contents under directory folder but keep directory an empty folder. But directory/** will delete everything including directory itself.

Comment: I would think of * as a wild card for everything within the directory. It has no influence on directories themselves. ** as a wild card for files and directories.